# Can't text compare Django model field

Tags: django, django-models, foreign-keys

I have a "Report" model set up in Django that represents a specific report uploaded to the site. This model has a ForeignKey relationship to a "UserTechnology" model which is a list of all the available ways an end user can access the uploaded reports.

I am displaying these reports and some information about them on the index.html page. I'd like to switch the url passed to the where we link the report based on the "UserTechnology" value that the specific report has.

The problem comes when trying to compare a report's UserTechnology value to anything. For example, if I just display `{{ report.UserTechnology }}` it works fine, with an example value of "FileManager". But if I try something like `{% "file" in report.UserTechnology %}` or `{% report.UserTechnology == "FileManager %}` it always returns False.

I think the problem is that I'm not comparing what I think I'm comparing when dealing with ForeignKey relationships, but I'm not sure how to access the value of UserTechnology.Name for a specific report other than report.UserTechnology.

### models.py:

```
class Report(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=200, default=None, null=True)
    LastUpdated = models.DateTimeField('date published', default=None, 
    null=True)
    SharePointURL = models.CharField(max_length=500,default=None, null=True)
    FileManagerLocation = models.TextField(default=None, null=True)
    ReportText = models.CharField(max_length=400, default=None, null=True)
    ReportImage = models.ImageField(default=None, null=True)
    Category = models.ForeignKey(Category, default=None, null=True, 
    on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    UserTechnology = models.ForeignKey(UserTechnology, default=None, 
    null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name

class UserTechnology(models.Model):
    Name = models.CharField(max_length=50, default=None, null=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.Name
```

### Index.html:

```
{% for report in reports %}
    {% if forloop.counter0|divisibleby:4 %} <div class="row"> {%  endif %}
        <div class="col-lg-3 col-md-4 col-sm-6 portfolio-item">
            <div class="card h-100">
                <a href="{{ report.SharePointURL }}" target="_blank"><img class="card-img-top" id="reportImage" src="{{ report.ReportImage.url }}" alt=""></a>
                <div class="card-body">
                    <h4 class="card-title">
                        <a href="{{ report.SharePointURL }}" target="_blank">{{ report.Name }}</a>
                    </h4>
                    <p class="card-text">{{ report.ReportText }}</p>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div> <!-- portfolio-item -->
{%  if forloop.counter|divisibleby:4 or forloop.last %}</div><!-- row closing --><hr>{%  endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`report.UserTechnology` is a ForeignKey, it points to the whole UserTechnology object. If you want to compare with a string, you'll need to compare with one of the fields on the object:

```
{% if report.UserTechnology.Name == "FileManager %}
```

Comment: I figured I was missing something basic like that. Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

When you render report.UserTechnology in your template, the Django templating language implicitly returns the hidden class method **str** on UserTechnology, but this isn't what you're comparing against for equality.

If you want to compare a report.UserTechnology with a string, you need to specify the corresponding attribute.

ie, report.UserTechnology.Name == 'FileManager'.

When you compare report.UserTechnology to 'FileManager' you are comparing a report.UserTechnology object. < UserTechnology: 2 > == 'FileManager' is False.

A good way to see this live is to use a stack trace in your code.

In your view logic you can add `import pdb; pdb.set_trace()`. When you run your code, the server will stop at that point, try running a few print statements against your report object.

Comment: Thanks, that trace information will be helpful in the future.